# Creating a Generic Function to convert an Array into a Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, generics, unity-game-engine

I have a struct which contains two public variables. I have made an array of that struct, and wish to convert it to a Dictionary.

Here is one such method of accomplishing that:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public struct KeyValuePairs
    {
        public string variableOne;
        public float variableTwo
    }

    private KeyValuePairs[] keyValuePairs;

    private Dictionary<string, float> KeyValuePairsToDictionary()
    {
        Dictionary<string, float> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, float>();

        for(int i = 0; i < keyValuePairs.Length; i++)
        {
            dictionary.Add(keyValuePairs[i].variableOne, keyValuePairs[i].variableTwo);
        }

        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

Now, that works for my specific setup, but I wish to try and convert the `KeyValuePairsToDictionary()` function into a Generic so that it may work across all types.

My first thought, then, was to do something like this:

```
private Dictionary<T, T> ArrayToDictionary<T>(T[] array)
{
    Dictionary<T, T> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<T, T>();

    for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        keyValuePairs.Add(array[i], array[i]); //The problem is right here.
    }

    return keyValuePairs;
}
```

As you can probably tell, I can't access the public fields of whatever struct array I am trying to convert into key-value pairs.

With that, how would you suggest I go about performing the generic conversion?

Please note that my specific setup requires that I convert a struct to a dictionary, for I am using the Unity Game Engine.

Thank you.

Comment: `Dictionary<T, T>` should be `Dictionary<T1, T2>` BTW why a generic method and why not an extension method?

Comment: Yeah you need two different type parameters so they need to be named differently.

Comment: You can create a generic extension method that converts `KeyValuePairs[]` to a dictionary

Comment: Also you can’t access properties of a generic type unless you filter using “where T: someType”. You could pass two Func parameters that are just lambas that are the “selectors” to the properties you want.

Comment: @Rahul @maccettura I can't rename to `Dictionary<T1, T2>`.  `The type or namespace name 'T1' could not be found.`

Comment: I am confused though. Why not use the default KeyValuePair<>?

Comment: A generic extension funtion would work for my purposes as well, I just don't know how to make it generic and access the public fields of a struct.

Comment: @JamieCorkhill You could just use Linq's `.ToDictionary()`.  [Docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @maccettura that was my though as well. Hence my confusion. I wasn't sure this question was a result of some limitation in unity

Comment: @Nkosi Yeah I was on mobile earlier and didnt see the custom struct for key and value.  This question does not make a whole lot of sense, it feels like an XY Problem

Comment: @maccettura @Nkosi Thank you. I can use the `ToDictionary()` function in Unity. I wanted to try and see if I could implement it without abstracting detail. I don't have to do that, of course, but I wish to better understand what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: @JamieCorkhill You literally cannot abstract any more than a generic, `IEnumerable` extension...  Also, dont roll your own struct for this.  `KeyValuePair` already exists.

Comment: @maccettura Okay, then. So you think the best way to do it would be to make an `IEnumerbale` extension function or class and make the conversion there, rather than using a Generic function? Thank you.

Comment: @JamieCorkhill no, thats not what I am saying at all.  Explain your problem in plain english, do not try to describe the problem with your proposed solution.  Tell us what the _actual_ problem you are trying to solve it.  Read up on what an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) is

Comment: @maccettura The struct is actually called `PrefabKeyValuePair` in my implementation, but I changed it so that you didn't have to Unity to understand the question.

Comment: @maccettura Sorry, I misread your comment. I believe you were saying that going my route actually abstracts more detail, which is the opposite of what I wish to do.

Comment: @JamieCorkhill Just tell us what your actual problem is, we cannot help you until you do.

Comment: @maccettura My problem is that I want to understand the best way to take a struct where I may not know the type of its two public variables within, and convert it to a dictionary. I understand that I can use the `ToDictionary()` function of `System.LINQ`, but I want to understand how I would do it if that method did not exist. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @maccettura  I have to set it up this way because Unity allows you to edit public variables in the Inspector. It does not, however, allow you to edit public Dictionaries. So, in order to get access from the Inspector, I have to make a `Serializable` struct, convert it to a public array, edit that public array in the Unity Inspector, and then convert it to a dictionary.

Comment: @JamieCorkhill Is there a reason you cannot use `ToDictionary()`?  If you want to see how `ToDictionary()` works you can just [look at the source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174567/discussion-between-jamie-corkhill-and-maccettura).

Answer (score 4):

A generic way of doing this is already implemented in LINQ.

```
var dict = myArray.ToDictionary(a => a.TheKey);
```

---

With your implementation

```
public struct KeyValuePairs
{
    public string variableOne;
    public float variableTwo;
}
```

and an array

```
KeyValuePairs[] keyValuePairs = ...;
```

You get

```
Dictionary<string, KeyValuePairs> dict = keyValuePairs
    .ToDictionary(a => a.variableOne);
```

or alternatively

```
Dictionary<string, float> dict = keyValuePairs
    .ToDictionary(a => a.variableOne, a => a.variableTwo);
```

Note that the first variant yields a dictionary with values of type `KeyValuePairs`, while the second one yields values of type `float`.

---

According to the conversation, it seems that you are interested on how you would implement this. Here is a suggestion:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> ToDictionary<T, TKey, TValue>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, TKey> getKey,
    Func<T, TValue> getValue)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    foreach (T item in source) {
        dict.Add(getKey(item), getValue(item));
    }
    return dict;
}
```

Or simply like this, if you want to store the item itself as value

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, T> ToDictionary<T, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, TKey> getKey
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<TKey, T>();
    foreach (T item in source) {
        dict.Add(getKey(item), item);
    }
    return dict;
}
```

Comment: If you want a `Dictionary<string, float>` the value selector is required, otherwise you get a `Dictionary<string, KeyValuePairs>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reflection to achieve that

First of all, add a `{get;set;}` to the variables to transform them in properties

```
public struct KeyValuePairs
{
    public string variableOne { get; set; }
    public float variableTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Then the method

```
// T1 -> Type of variableOne
// T2 -> Type of variableTwo
// T3 -> KeyValuesPair type
public static Dictionary<T1, T2> convert<T1,T2,T3>(T3[] data)
{
    // Instantiate dictionary to return
    Dictionary<T1, T2> dict = new Dictionary<T1, T2>();

    // Run through array
    for (var i = 0;i < data.Length;i++)
    {
        // Get 'key' value via Reflection to variableOne
        var key = data[i].GetType().GetProperty("variableOne").GetValue(data[i], null);
        // Get 'value' value via Reflection to variableTow
        var value = data[i].GetType().GetProperty("variableTwo").GetValue(data[i], null);
        // Add 'key' and 'value' to dictionary casting to properly type
        dict.Add((T1)key, (T2)value);
    }
    //return dictionary
    return dict;
}
```

I used the following code to test

```
KeyValuePairs[] val = new KeyValuePairs[5];

val[0] = new KeyValuePairs() { variableOne = "a", variableTwo = 2.4f };
val[1] = new KeyValuePairs() { variableOne = "b", variableTwo = 3.5f };
val[2] = new KeyValuePairs() { variableOne = "c", variableTwo = 4.6f };
val[3] = new KeyValuePairs() { variableOne = "d", variableTwo = 5.7f };
val[4] = new KeyValuePairs() { variableOne = "e", variableTwo = 6.8f };

Dictionary<string, float> dict = convert<string, float,KeyValuePairs>(val);
```